# Blogger conditional tag depending on on screen size

Tags: javascript, xml, blogger

I would like to know how to get screen size in xml.
I want to execute the following conditional statement only if (screen.width> 768px):

```
<b: if cond = 'data: blog.pageType ! = & quot; item & quot;'>
"HTML content"
</ b: if>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can not detect screen width by Blogger. You can achieve that using CSS like the following

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
    <style>
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            /* css code */
        }
    </style>
</b:if>
```